# Многопоточность в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вопрос опытным программистам, которые много работали с потоками. Есть классы CountDownLatch, CyclicBarrier, Semaphore, Phaser, Exchanger. Часто ли приходится сталкиваться с ними? И если можете, коротко опишите их плюсы и недостатки, или различия.

Comment: Обычно, насколько я понимаю, пользуются намного более высокоуровневыми конструкциями.

Comment: @VladD, это они и есть. Низкоуровневые это `synchronized`, `Thread`, `wait()` и `notify()`.

Comment: Отличная статья с визуализациями по синхронизаторам из `java.util.concurrent` - https://habrahabr.ru/post/277669/

Comment: Из перечисленных, на мой взгляд, самый популярный (потому что самый простой) - `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: @Nofate: Правда? В платформе Империи Зла они практически не используются, а разветвление flow выражается в терминах промисов (async/await).